# Facial Recognition Attack Nomenclature

Tags: terminology, facial-recognition

Is there a generally acknowledged **term** for spoofing facial recognition with a photo of the target face (Samsung smartphone facial recognition, not Apple FaceID (depth measurement)).

Comment: This looks like a research project into academic articles: https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_workshops_2014/W01/papers/Hadid_Face_Biometrics_under_2014_CVPR_paper.pdf